# How to read binary data in IE9?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on some Javascript code that creates an alpha mask of a image using paths embedded by Photoshop. The onload handler of a IMG tag would call a clip(this). The function load the image's source file and scans through it. Here's the setup:

```
function clip(img) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', img.src, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.target = img;

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        var p = findPhotoshopSegment(bytes);
        if(p) {
            var paths = parse8BIMData(bytes, p);

            /* ... replaces IMG with SVG tag ... */
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

You can see the code in action at http://flaczki.net46.net/JPEG/SVG.html

Currently, it only works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. It doesn't work in IE9. The browser supports SVG but not Uint8Array. Is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: Use Google Chrome Frame on the page https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Comment: "It doesn't work in IE9" is not an error message - if you want to play with the sharp knives then you really need to do some of the work yourself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had same issue while playing with pdf.js library, and solution I found is to make my own  Uint8Array, below is code which you need. All credits goes to **notmasteryet**@github and full code can be found here https://gist.github.com/1057924

```
(function() {
  try {
    var a = new Uint8Array(1);
    return; //no need
  } catch(e) { }

  function subarray(start, end) {
    return this.slice(start, end);
  }

  function set_(array, offset) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) offset = 0;
    for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i, ++offset)
      this[offset] = array[i] & 0xFF;
  }

  // we need typed arrays
  function TypedArray(arg1) {
    var result;
    if (typeof arg1 === "number") {
       result = new Array(arg1);
       for (var i = 0; i < arg1; ++i)
         result[i] = 0;
    } else
       result = arg1.slice(0);
    result.subarray = subarray;
    result.buffer = result;
    result.byteLength = result.length;
    result.set = set_;
    if (typeof arg1 === "object" && arg1.buffer)
      result.buffer = arg1.buffer;

    return result;
  }

  window.Uint8Array = TypedArray;
  window.Uint32Array = TypedArray;
  window.Int32Array = TypedArray;
})();
```

Comment: Excellent! Now my code works in IE too. That was a nice turn-key solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Milan Jaric I tried using your code but i can't get it to work. can u show me how i would use this to replace my Uint8Array which isn't working on safari.. thanks... here is my code. var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629868/web-audio-analyser-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Could you please provide error from safari console log? It is hard to tell what is issue cause I don't have IOS to test your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be assured you get wider range of compatibility, you can also use the compatibility.js file included in the PDF.js distribution under the "web" directory.
Get PDF.js from [Mozilla Github](http://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), decompress the zip archive and include the compatibility.js file from the above directory. It also makes PDF.js library work in e.g. IE9

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to use PDF.js on Windows Phone? I'm having dreadful problems accessing XHR where I'm getting 'Access is denied'. I'm still researching it and playing around trying different path but hopefully you'll be able to provide me with some insight on how to use it with wp8.1