# Read binary in IE9 with jQuery and jDataView

Tags: javascript, jquery, binary, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to read binary with [jDataView](https://github.com/vjeux/jDataView) on 2 browsers : Chrome and IE9.

I added the new type `binary` before the ajax request (using jQuery 1.10.0) :

```
// Install binary dataType
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    accepts: {
        binary: "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"
    },
    contents: {

    },
    converters: {
        "text binary": true // Nothing to convert
    }
});
```

For the server returning the binary stream, I added the header :

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251"); ?>
```

Then the ajax request :

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'binary',
    mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined',
    success: function(data) {
        var view = new jDataView(data);
        // ...
    }
});
```

I'm using the method `getUint8()` to get a portion of the binary stream :

```
for (var l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
    tx += " " + view.getUint8(l, true);
}
```

Then, comparing the `tx` strings :

```
0 0 0 7 12 106 212 65 (chrome) => GOOD (match the expected results)
0 0 2 94 12 106 36 65 (IE9) => 3 BAD sequences
```

With Chrome it works just fine, but I don't have the same results with IE9... Chrome is using native `getUint8` function while IE9 is using jDataView method.

Comment: Check two things: 1) your `for` cycle has identical `l` value on each iteration. If so, it's not enough code in question to figure out why; 2) server response is equals when you get it from both browsers. If so, trouble in getUint8 method of jDataView; github has something like bugtracker on Issues tab, report there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution with this [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047504/858523) and jDataView :

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

if (oReq.overrideMimeType) {
    oReq.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
} else {
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept-Charset', 'x-user-defined');
}

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
        var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
        var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        var dataView = new jDataView(view.buffer);
        // ...
    }
};
```